# switching between video cards when doing different tasks

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I have 2 NVidia Geforce GTX 560 video cards that are in SLI. However I want to add a video card that is strictly for rendering vector files (something that my gaming cards suck at) is there a way to set the vector card to only run when autocad or a similar program is operational? Without physically switching the cards? I am running windows 7 ultimate.

Thanks guys

Comment: The rendering software may have an option that will let you specify which card it should run calculations on. I would give that a go first.

Comment: I just checked, it has no preference settings for rendering in AUTOCAD or Vectorworks